# TemplateSyntaxError at Could not parse the remainder

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, jinja2

In my django app I am trying to get the name of image to be loaded from JSON variable.In its HTML key there is name of the image to be displayed.
I am reading that key and appending in the static path.But I get this error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at  Could not parse the remainder
```

JSON

```
 var json = [{
        "html": "abc.jpg", //testing this failed
        "col": 1,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    }, {
        "html": "def.jpg", 
        "col": 4,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    },

    {
        "html": "bac.jpg",
        "col": 6,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    },


    {
        "html": "xyz.jpg",
        "col": 1,
        "row": 3,
        "size_y": 1,
        "size_x": 1
    }, {
        "html": "Brand.jpg",
        "col": 4,
        "row": 3,
        "size_y": 1,
        "size_x": 1
    },

    {
        "html": "Brand.jpg",
        "col": 6,
        "row": 3,
        "size_y": 1,
        "size_x": 1
    }

    ];
```

My loop used for extracting image name and other required parameters

```
for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
   gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static \'images/'+json[index].html+'\' %}"></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
};
```

Check in this loop the variable I get

```js
var json = [{
    "html": "abc.jpg", //testing this failed
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "def.jpg",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "bac.jpg",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "xyz.jpg",
    "col": 1,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }, {
    "html": "Brand.jpg",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }, {
    "html": "Brand.jpg",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }
];

for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
   console.log('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static \'images/'+json[index].html+'\' %}"></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
};
```

Comment: `{% static \'images/'+json[index].html+'\' %}` - you can't do this - the template is rendered on the server, before your browser runs the JavaScript loop.

Comment: So how to load the image in that case I want to load the image from server corresponding to name in json

Comment: If `json` is defined in the template, you could use the `static` tag there. Or you might find it easiest to remove the static tag and hardcode the prefix.

Comment: just hardcode the prefix as in put server address ? http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. However you don't need the domain, `/static/images/` would do.

Comment: Also to give you an idea my template is somewhat like this https://jsfiddle.net/52oxn6g9/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167342/discussion-between-rookie-123-and-alasdair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% static \'images/'+json[index].html+'\' %}
```

You can't do this because the `{% static %}` template tag is rendered on the server *before* the browser runs your JavaScript.

You could use the [`get_static_prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix) tag (note this won't work for all static files storage backends).

```
{% load static %}
"{% get_static_prefix %}" + json[index].html
```

Or, since you define `json` in your template, you could use `static` repeatedly there.

```
var json = [{ 
"html": "abc.jpg", //testing this failed 
"image": "{% static "abc.jpg" %}", 
...
```

Then use `image` in your loop.